# What part in GeckoFX returns System or Browser footprint information?

Tags: c#, xulrunner, geckofx

I decided for a project to build my own secure custom-firefox-version for TOR (although TOR-Bundle does a pretty good job, it's still predictable and easy to spot) I need it to have a real anti footprint capability (ie: can fake and spoof system screen resolution, plugins count, fake plugin names, plugin versions, system fonts, system timezones, and other system variables..) and I wish to go low level for this.

I'm using C# and GeckoFX29 with its appropriate XULRunner, but it seems impossible to even affect the (`screen`.width) object in javascript through C#. Now since everything is open source I decided I have to make changes in as low level as I have to so I can learn by recompiling and testing until I figure this out.

Problem is, I'm not sure what part to download and change so far, I may be wrong but I doubt it's GeckoFX and even the XULRunner itself as they look to me more like a wrapper/gateway to something else inside them. I need to know for sure what part has to change, and would want to know if it's doable, not crazy hard to compile, and worth my time investment. Has anyone had any luck with this before?